# Mostra dias com malote ignorando o dia de hoje com retorno JSON

Tags: php, json

Estou tentando fazer uma lógica para exibir o próximo dia que um determinado entreposto terá envio de malote, estou tentando criar um `array` com a busca que estou fazendo em meu `banco de dados` e tentando ignorar o dia de hoje e sempre ver o próximo dia, mas sem sucesso.
No meu banco os dias são 0 e 1, sendo que 0 não haverá malote e 1, sim.

O meu banco está assim:

[image: Imagem do banco de dados]

O que tenho de código está assim:

```
if (GetApplication()->isGetValueSet('IdUnicoop')) {
    $IdUnicoop = GetApplication()->GetGETValue('IdUnicoop');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dvsMaloteDias WHERE dvsMaloteDias.IdUnicoop = $IdUnicoop";
    $queryResult = $this->GetConnection()->fetchAll($sql);

    $Notificacao = array();

              foreach($queryResult as $RegResult) {           

            if ($RegResult['Segunda'] != 0) {       
                array_push($Notificacao, "Segunda");
            }
            if ($RegResult['Terça'] != 0) {     
                array_push($Notificacao, "Terça");
            }
            if ($RegResult['Quarta'] != 0) {        
                array_push($Notificacao, "Quarta");
            }       
            if ($RegResult['Quinta'] != 0) {        
                array_push($Notificacao, "Quinta");
            }
            if ($RegResult['Sexta'] != 0) {     
                array_push($Notificacao, "Sexta");
            }
            if ($RegResult['Sabado'] != 0) {        
                array_push($Notificacao, "Sábado");
            }
            if ($RegResult['Domimgo']!= 0) {        
                array_push($Notificacao, "Domingo");
            }
            if ($RegResult['Todos'] != 0) {     
                array_push($Notificacao, "Todos");
            }          

        }


    $result = array(
        'Notificacao' => 'O próximo dia do malote é: ' . $Notificacao
    );

    echo json_encode($result);
    exit;                              
}
```

De acordo com a imagem, por exemplo, o entreposto 9 tem malote na segunda, mas devo verificar que dia é hoje e se for segunda, tenho que mostra que haverá malote na quarta e na quarta, verificar o dia e se for quarta, mostrar sexta.

Até consegui descobrir o dia da semana, mas a comparação não, vejam:

```
    $now = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
    $minhadataYmdHis = $now->format('Y-m-d');

    $diaSemanaN= date("w", strtotime($minhadataYmdHis));

    switch($diaSemanaN) {
        case 0:
        $diaSemana="Domingo";
        break;
        case 1:
        $diaSemana="Segunda";
        break;  
        case 2:
        $diaSemana="Terça";
        break;  
        case 3:
        $diaSemana="Quarta";
        break;
        case 4:
        $diaSemana="Quinta";
        break;  
        case 5:
        $diaSemana="Sexta";
        break;          
        case 6:
        $diaSemana="Sábado";
        break;              
    }

    echo $diaSemana;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá.

Isso é um problema de lógica. Geralmente não é algo que deve ser resolvido aqui.

Porém vou te dar um código que funciona, mas não está 100% lapidado. Esse código não verifica por exemplo quando todos os dias tem malote. E tem mais um problema nele que você deve resolver. Se hoje for quinta-feira e tiver um malote na segunda, ele não será capaz de te avisar isso.

```php
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');

$simulacaoBanco = [
    [
        "idUnicoop" => 1,
        "Segunda" => 1,
        "Terca" => 0,
        "Quarta" => 1,
        "Quinta" => 0,
        "Sexta" => 1,
        "Sabado" => 0,
        "Domingo" => 0,
        "Todos" => 0
    ]    
];
//percorre todos linha a linha vinda do banco, no exemplo há somente uma linha
foreach($simulacaoBanco as $simulacao){
    $idUnicoop = $simulacao['idUnicoop'];
    unset($simulacao['idUnicoop']);
    $todos = $simulacao['Todos'];
    unset($simulacao['Todos']);
    $simulacao = array_values($simulacao); //reseta o array para indices numericos 
começando de segunda = 0
    $diaSemana = date('w', time()); //pega o dia da semana começando de domingo = 0;
    if($diaSemana === 0){
        $diaSemana = 6; //é o domingo vindo do banco
    }else{
        $diaSemana = $diaSemana - 1; //hoje segunda é = 1 mas no banco é 0 então por 
isso a subtração para igualar os dias
    }
    foreach($simulacao as $diaBanco => $temMalote){
        if($diaBanco > $diaSemana){
            if($temMalote === 1){
                //dia atual + dia vindo do banco = proximo dia com malote
                echo 'Na ' . date('l', strtotime('+' . ($diaBanco) . ' days'  , 
time())) . ' tem malote.' . PHP_EOL; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @MatheusPrado pela dica, mas não entendi o comentário sobre a lógica, se estou tendo problema com ela e por isso postei o código que já tinha feito aqui, justamente por estar buscando ajuda.

Comment: Geralmente os problemas postados aqui são de erros com funções ou de sintaxe ou quem sabe com problemas inesperados. Se você tivesse um código que já fizesse o que precisa que ele faça, mas que gere erros ou funcione de forma inesperada, seria outra historia.